Why did USA agree that early in 1941 about the Germany First strategic plan (if so)?
I have read a surprising information on some websites that apparently are truthsworthy enough:
One unknown site

During the first three weeks of January 1941 the planners of the Joint Board completed their arrangements for the American-British Staff Conference. On 21 January they submitted to the board a proposed agenda for the meetings and a statement of the American position. The meetings were to be nonpolitical; no specific commitments were to be made (except for methods of co-operation) and agreements reached would be subject to approval by the two governments. Within this framework, the delegates were to determine the best methods by which the forces of both nations could defeat Germany and its allies should the United States be "compelled to resort to war"-a phrase introduced by the President; reach agreement on the methods and nature of military co-operation; and co-ordinate plans for the use of their forces.
As a guide for the delegates, American national objectives were
defined in virtually the same terms that Admiral Stark used: (1)
Protection of the Western Hemisphere against military or political
encroachment by any other power; (2) Aid to the British Commonwealth:
(3) Opposition by diplomatic means to Japanese expansion. In the event
of war, the "broad military objective" of the United States and
Britain would be the defeat of Germany, which would be "most
effectively attained" by placing the principal military effort in the
Atlantic, or "navally in the Mediterranean"-another presidential
phrase. In the way of practical advice in negotiating with the
British, the delegates were to keep the following in mind:

An American museum site

Earlier in 1941, the United States and the United Kingdom had agreed upon a strategic approach of “Germany First” in the event of a two-front war against Nazi Germany in Europe and Imperial Japan in the Pacific

What surprises me in this information is that the Americans could have agreed upon fighting Germany first even before being in a state of war against Japan. In 1940 the oil ban was already in action but, still, the purpose of that blocus was to deny Japan the capability of war, and other actions such as placing B-17 in Philippnes were thought to deter Japan from war. They did not know the exact situation of war they would face if war was about to start. Also, such an agreement in early 1941 causes to wonder about why, later, the American government was unable to anticipate the Japanese attack in December.
What is also weird to me is that American territories and related territories (Philippines...) were more vulnerable to Japan than to Germany.
So, my question:

Is this information reliable ?
If yes, why did the USA considered that early that Germany should be first to be fought?


Please edit the title of your question. Even after reading the complete question, I am not sure what that sentence is supposed to ask. Also, please explain the non-existant word "blocus".

?  Why did the USA choose to defeat Germany before Japan? ??

@ccprog i edited
MCW This is not my question: my previous knowledge about germany first was that it was decided in 1942 and after Midway: in any case, after Japan entered the world war. I'm curious to understand why they could have engaged themselves on this strategic decision

A good source on this is the relevant volume of the US Official History,
which is Chief of Staff: Prewar Plans and Preparations. That does not address the specific point in a single section, but a key point was Roosevelt's strategy statement of 16 January 1941 (pp. 124-25), which was:

That we would stand on the defensive in the Pacific with the fleet based on Hawaii; that the Commander of the Asiatic Fleet would have discretionary authority as to how long he could remain based in the Philippines and as to his direction of withdrawal—to the East or to Singapore; that there would be no naval reinforcement of the Philippines; that the Navy should have under consideration the possibility of bombing attacks against Japanese cities.
That the Navy should be prepared to convoy shipping in the Atlantic to England, and to maintain a patrol off-shore from Maine to the Virginia Capes.
That the Army should not be committed to any aggressive action until it was fully prepared to undertake it; that our military course must be very conservative until our strength had developed; that it was assumed we could provide forces sufficiently trained to assist to a moderate degree in backing up friendly Latin-American governments against Nazi inspired fifth column movements.
That we should make every effort to go on the basis of continuing the supply of materiel to Great Britain, primarily in order to disappoint what he thought would be Hitler's principal objective in involving us in a war at this particular time, and also to buck up England.

Searching the book for mentions of "Germany" makes the thinking behind this policy clearer. Germany's rapid conquest of Europe raised real fears of an invasion of South America, and keeping the UK in the war provided a base for an eventual invasion of Europe to defeat Germany and Italy.
In contrast, a Japanese invasion of the Americas wasn't seen as credible. It would have been hard, simply because of the vast distances in the Eastern Pacific between the American coast and any plausible Japanese base. Remember that Pearl Harbour was assumed to be too far from Japan to be seriously attacked, until that was disproven.

Quite right. It's almost always a good strategy to focus on defeating the strongest/most dangerous enemy first, and that would be Germany. Defeating Japan while Germany rolled up Europe, Africa and the UK would leave us alone in a very dangerous position. Defeating Germany would leave Japan to be dealt with, but that was always a more solvable problem.

Thank you for those elements, this backs up the fact that the idea of defeating Germany First was already thought about in early 1941. Overall, we could say that Japan was understimated because its real achievements in early 1942 threatened largely more Allied positions in the Pacific than what is written here

The effort to defeat Japan was a small fraction of what was used to defeat Germany, and was recognized as such even when Japan 'over achieved' pre-war expectations (of either side). Now, if Japan had taken, say, California (yes, impossible) then the calculus might have changed.
